# Using current scope as kwargs in python

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I basically want to expand the current scope as you would a dictionary when calling a function.

I remember seeing something about this somewhere but I cannot remember where or how to do it.

Here is a simple example

```
def bar(a, b, c, d, e, f):
    pass

def foo(a, b, c, d, e, f):
    # Instead of doing this
    bar(a, b, c, d, e, f)
    # or
    bar(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, e=e, f=f)
    # I'd like to do this
    bar(**local_scope)
```

Am I imagining things or can this really be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `locals()` (or `globals()` depending on what you need), which returns a dictionary mapping variable names to values.

```
bar(**locals())
```

Comment: Perfect! I just had to add `*args, **kwargs` to the argument list in `bar` since I add a few local variables in my `foo` function

Answer (score 3):

if foo was written like this

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    bar(**kwargs)
```

Other than that the other two examples you posted are better, expanding all locals is a bad idea.

Comment: I cannot use **kwargs in the first function, it takes arguments from funcargs